# Factorial Equivalencies Calculus

Tags: factorial

Why is:

```
(2n+1)! = (2n)(2n+1)(2n-1)!
```

Using this, I can deduce that:

```
(n+1)! = (n)(n+1)(n-1)!
```

I am working with Calculus Sequences. The actual problem is:

Find whether the Sequence converges or diverges:

```
{(2n-1)!/(2n+1)!}
```

Comment: Please tell me why I deserve -1 and I will gladly fix it.

Comment: What definition of factorial are you familiar with?  Are you allowed to use the usual recurrence, $n! = n (n-1)!$ ?

Comment: The expression simplifies to $\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)}$, which clearly converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
(2n+1)!=(2n+1)(2n+1-1)(2n+1-2)\cdots 1
$$
And 
$$ (2n-1)!=(2n+1-2)\cdots 1 $$
So
$$
(2n+1)!=(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)!
$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that $n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\ldots(n-1)\cdot n$. If you divide both sides through by $n$, the right hand side becomes the product of $1\cdot2\cdot3\ldots$ up to $(n-1)$. This is $(n-1)!$ so we can see that $n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$ for all natural numbers $n$. If you set substitute $n$ with $2n$, your equation holds.

I'm not sure about the downvote though perhaps it's cause some people define $n!$ as $n(n-1)!$, which would make your statement obvious.